# What are those new files after Activator 1.3.5 update?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

Today while starting my Play app with `activator run` the new Activator version 1.3.5 got installed automatically. My app's running perfectly fine. But now I see a couple of new files in my app's folder and I don't know what they are or how to handle them. Maybe someone can advice me. Google didn't help me much so far. Those files are

- .sbtserver
- .sbtserver.lock
- play-fork-run.sbt
- sbt-ui.sbt

Except for the .sbtserver.lock they all look like configuration files. But what are they configuring? And should I put them under version control?

Answer (score 1):

For **.sbtserver** and **.sbtserver.lock** I found in the [sbt reference](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Launcher-Architecture.html):

> The configured server.lock file is thus used to prevent multiple servers from running. Sbt itself uses this to prevent more than one server running on any given project directory by configuring server.lock to be ${user.dir}/.sbtserver.

So they seem to be there to prevent Activator to start the same server application twice. They can be deleted without any problems.

And for **play-fork-run.sbt** and **sbt-ui.sbt**: In [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/1036) I found:

> ... a new project/play-fork-run.sbt file will get generated by Activator as it is needed to make Play apps run in the background in development mode.

So those seem to be generated by Activator if you run it via the Activator UI. I guess it's up to you and the kind of your project whether you keep them. I prefer Activator's command line interface and deleted both files without any problems.